# What suffices for showing $p \Leftrightarrow q \Leftrightarrow r$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to show that

$p \Leftrightarrow q  \Leftrightarrow  r$

where $p,q,r$ are logical sentences. Is it true that it suffices to show only $p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow r$?

Comment: provided I interpret your question correctly, $p\implies q\implies r \implies p$ is enough to show that $p\iff q\iff r$. The question you want to ask youself in such situations is: "Can I get everywhere from anywhere".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite: you need also to show that $r \Rightarrow p$.

So, to show that three propositions are logically equivalent, i.e., to show that $$p \Leftrightarrow q\Leftrightarrow r,$$ it suffices to prove the following chain of implications: $$p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow r \Rightarrow p.$$

and you can do this by showing that $$(p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow r) \land (r\Rightarrow p).$$

Comment: Ok, I have one question yet. Is it true that I can show that $p \Leftrightarrow q$ and $q  \Leftrightarrow  r$  ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we mean by $p \Leftrightarrow q \Leftrightarrow r$, which is by definition the same claim as is "$p \Leftrightarrow q \land q\Leftrightarrow r$. Also, feel free to accept the answer, if it's been helpful!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU -->> +1

Answer (score 4):

Considering the alphabet $p,q,r$, and depending on what these stand for; you can show some things like:
$$p \Leftrightarrow q, q\Rightarrow r\Rightarrow p  \\ p\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow r\Rightarrow p\\ p \Leftrightarrow r, r\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow p$$

Comment: Ditto for your answer, can use another TU! +1